# How to merge several lists into one in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a function like this:

```
sheet_vector <- c("results1.xlsx", "results2.xlsx", "results3.xlsx", "results4.xlsx")
results_list <- vector("list", length = length(sheet_vector))

for(i in seq_along(sheet_vector)){
  results_df <- readxl::read_xlsx(paste0("O:\\mypath\\",sheet_vector[i]),sheet = "finalresult")

  results_list[[i]] <- results_df
  names(results_list)[i] <- sheet_vector[i]
}
```

What I get in the element `results_list` is a list of 4 S3 elements that all have the same name and the same structure. It looks like this:

```
List of 4
 $ testdata1: tibble [181 x 47] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ person        : chr [1:181] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ item1         : num [1:181] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...
  ..$ item2         : num [1:181] 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 ...
[...]
$ testdata1: tibble [108 x 47] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ person        : chr [1:108] "201" "202" "203" "204" ...
  ..$ item1         : num [1:108] 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ item2         : num [1:108] 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 ...
[...]
$ testdata1: tibble [154 x 47] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ person        : chr [1:154] "401" "402" "403" "404" ...
  ..$ item1         : num [1:154] 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ item2         : num [1:154] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
[...]
$ testdata1: tibble [19 x 47] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ person        : chr [1:19] "601" "602" "603" "604" ...
  ..$ item1         : num [1:19] 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 ...
  ..$ item2         : num [1:19] 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
[...]
```

I would like to merge the 4 elements in `results_list` into one single list by combining the respective columns.

It should look like this:

```
List of 1
 $ testdata1: tibble [462 x 47] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ person        : chr [1:462] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ item1         : num [1:462] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...
  ..$ item2         : num [1:462] 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 ...
[...]
```

Ideally, at the end of the loop, the element `results_df` should contain all data from the four excel lists combined. As it is right now, it contains only the data from the last excel sheet (`results4.xlsx`).

I really appreciate your help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `do.call(rbind,results_list)`.

Comment: Just use `purrr` instead of a loop for a simple one liner, `purrr::map_dfr(sheet_vector, ~readxl::read_xlsx(paste0("O:\\mypath\\",.x),sheet = "finalresult")`

Comment: `data.table::rbindlist(results_list)` will bind everything into one `data.table`. If you want the result to be a list, call `list()` on result. If for some / all `tibble`s some / all column names differ add argument `fill = TRUE` to the `rbindlist()` call.

Comment: You can also use `dplyr::bind_rows`. This, and the `purrr` and `data.table` approach are _much_ more efficient than `do.call` with `rbind`.